# Making dynamic cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I need to change cell height dynamicalli when button clicked. I solve this. But i want to count cell content size and then if need add button which changed cell height i show buttton, if not i dont show button

```
@IBOutlet weak var descLbl: UILabel!  
var descBtn_active=false
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.backgroundView=UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "white_bg"))
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight=50
    tableView.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    img.downloadImageFrom(link: "http://k-p.kz/"+(message?["img"].string)!, contentMode: .scaleToFill)    
    descLbl.text=message?["content"].string
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        return descBtn_active ? UITableViewAutomaticDimension : 65
    default:
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}

@IBAction func descDetailAct(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    (sender as? UIButton)?.setTitle(descBtn_active ? "далее" : "скрыть", for: .normal)
    descBtn_active=descBtn_active ? false : true
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

How i can do this?

Comment: print("_____________________________________"yourcell.contentView.frame.size.height);

Comment: for changing height increase  yourcell.contentView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)